# Converting XML to CSV using xsltproc with complicated file

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I've a big XML file that I am desperately trying to convert it into a CSV file with `xsltproc`.

All the data I wish to extract can be found under `[GRP alias="TRIUT" level="5"]`.

What I need are only these tags of the file:

- Matricule
- Name
- Value of Mount1 from the "Rubrique" 976 of the ELEMENT_1

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RPT>
   <GRP alias="Reglementation" level="1">
      <FLD id="Reglementation">USA</FLD>
      <GRP alias="RUPT1" level="2">
         <FLD id="RUPT1" />
         <GRP alias="RUPT2" level="3">
            <FLD id="RUPT2" />
            <GRP alias="RUPT3" level="4">
               <FLD id="RUPT3" />
               <GRP alias="TRIUT" level="5">
                  <FLD id="TRIUT">00-532</FLD>
                  <DTL>
                     <FLD id="DateEdition" type="DATE">2017-02-01</FLD>
                     <FLD id="Name">MR CHARLIE CHAPLIN</FLD>
                     <FLD id="Matricule">12345678</FLD>
                     <SRPT id="ELEMENT_1">
                        <DTL>
                           <FLD id="Rubrique">038</FLD>
                           <FLD id="Mount1" type="FLOAT">2200.95</FLD>
                           <FLD id="Mount2" type="FLOAT">00000.00</FLD>
                        </DTL>
                        <DTL>
                           <FLD id="Rubrique">976</FLD>
                           <FLD id="Mount1">9926.96</FLD>
                           <FLD id="Mount2">00000.00</FLD>
                        </DTL>
                     </SRPT>
                  </DTL>
               </GRP>
               <GRP alias="TRIUT" level="5">
                  <FLD id="TRIUT">00186</FLD>
                  <DTL>
                     <FLD id="DateEdition">2017-03-31</FLD>
                     <FLD id="Nom">MR JAMES BOND</FLD>
                     <FLD id="Matricule">00000007</FLD>
                     <SRPT id="ELEMENT_1">
                        <DTL>
                           <FLD id="Rubrique">038</FLD>
                           <FLD id="Mount1">2054.22</FLD>
                           <FLD id="Mount2">000000.00</FLD>
                        </DTL>
                        <DTL>
                           <FLD id="Rubrique">976</FLD>
                           <FLD id="Mount1">2054.22</FLD>
                           <FLD id="Mount2">00000.22</FLD>
                        </DTL>
                     </SRPT>
                  </DTL>
               </GRP>
            </GRP>
         </GRP>
      </GRP>
   </GRP>
</RPT>
```

What I want to see is:

```
Matricule;Name;Rubrique976_Mount1
12345678;MR CHARLIE CHAPLIN;9926.96
00000007;MR JAMES BOND;2054.22
```

Do you think it's possible ?

This is what i tried to do, but it doesnt answer at all to what i need...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:text>Matricule;Name;Rubrique976_Mount1</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>&amp;#xA;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each select="RPT/GRP/GRP/GRP/GRP/GRP/DTL">
         <xsl:for-each select="FLD">
            <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="SRPT">
               <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
               <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
               <xsl:value-of select="." />
               <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </xsl:for-each>
         <xsl:text>&amp;#xA;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is what I get, but not what I wanted...

```
Matricule;Name;Rubrique976_Mount1
DateEdition;2017-02-01;Name;MR CHARLIE CHAPLIN;Matricule;12345678;
DateEdition;2017-03-31;Nom;MR JAMES BOND;Matricule;00000007;
```

Thanks for people who want to rack their brain !

Comment: You should publish what you have tried, because even though it may not be working it does actually show you have tried something. And you never know, your XSLT might not be too far off what is required. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @TimC i just did it, but very very far from what i expect...

Answer (score 2):

You should start off by selecting `GRP` which have the matching attributes

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//GRP[@alias='TRIUT' and @level='5']" />
```

You can then have a template matching `GRP` which outputs the fields you need. For example, to output the "Matricule", it would look like this

```
<xsl:value-of select="DTL/FLD[@id='Matricule']" />
```

Outputting the "Value of Mount1 from the "Rubrique" 976 of the ELEMENT_1" is a bit more complicated because a number of conditions are involved:

```
<xsl:value-of select="DTL
                       /SRPT[@id='ELEMENT_1']
                        /DTL[FLD[@id='Rubrique']='976']
                         /FLD[@id='Mount1']" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>Matricule;Name;Rubrique976_Mount1&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//GRP[@alias='TRIUT' and @level='5']" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="GRP">
    <xsl:value-of select="DTL/FLD[@id='Matricule']" />
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="DTL/FLD[@id='Name' or @id='Nom']" />
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="DTL/SRPT[@id='ELEMENT_1']/DTL[FLD[@id='Rubrique']='976']/FLD[@id='Mount1']" />
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: To sort by "Matricule", change the `xsl:apply-templates` to have an `xsl:sort` statement, like so:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//GRP[@alias='TRIUT' and @level='5']">
    <xsl:sort select="DTL/FLD[@id='Matricule']" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Comment: i dont know what to tell...
when i see "answered 4 mins ago", it makes me crazy...

Thank you very much for your answer and almost for your detailed explainations !!!

Comment: Another improvement to ask...
Is there a way inside the template to sort the file directly by Matricule ?

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer to show how sorting can work.

Comment: When changing with the sort by "Matricule', i get some errors. Sorry I Can't put the code i get into the comment, because it displays badly.

Comment: I did make a mistake with my syntax, which I have now corrected.